# Quetion About The Proof of Noether's Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, classical-mechanics

My quetion is about the proof of Noether's theorem in Arnold *Mathematical Methods Of Classical Mechanics*.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, suppose the Lagrange function $L(q,\dot{q})$ is a smooth function on the tangent bundle $TM$.

Let $h^s:M\to M,s\in\mathbb{R}$ be a one-parameter group of diffeomorphism that satisfies
$$L(h^s_*v)=L(v),\forall v\in TM, \forall s\in\mathbb{R},$$
where $h_*$ is the pushforward induced by $h$.

Let $\varphi(t)$ be a solution of lagrange equation $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}=0$, and let $\Phi(s,t)=h^s(\varphi(t))$.

It seems that Arnold used $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\Phi=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s}\Phi$ in the proof, but I don't know why does it holds.

Comment: This should be partial derivatives, as there are two independent independent variables. The question you are asking is if $Φ$ is twice continuously differentiable, this is answered by the existence theorem for ODE and the theorems on smooth dependence on initial values and parameters (result as smooth or one order better than the inputs).

Comment: I know the smoothness with respect to $s$ and $t$ repectively, but I can't find the conclusion about the smoothness with respect to $(s,t)$.